# 400 Bad Request arduino esp8266

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

Hi i am trying to test a value form nodemcu board i am using arduino ide to code and have modified the WIFIClient example to send a value to my localhost using GET. it gives me bad request error. any help or suggestion is appreciated

**Modified WIFIClinet**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "ssid";
const char* password = "pwd";


const char* host = "http://10.0.0.39/edu/arduino.php";



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

int value = 0;

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  ++value;

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }




  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url ="?v=we";
//  
//  
 Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

// This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
              "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
//
unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
```

}

**Output from serial monitor**

```
connecting to http://10.0.0.39/edu/arduino.php
Requesting URL: ?v=we
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: httpd
Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2011 22:02:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>400 Bad Request</H4>
Bad filename.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpful for people running this on local host i changed

```
const char* host = "http://10.0.0.39/edu/arduino.php";
to 
const char* host = "10.0.0.39";
```

and

```
String url ="?v=we";
to 

String url ="/edu/arduino.php?v=we";
```